# How to send commands using SOAP to AzerothCore worldserver console?

Tags: php, soap, azerothcore, trinitycore

How can I run a command after enabling **SOAP to AzerothCore** worldserver console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to put on `worldserver.conf` these parameters to enable SOAP:

```
SOAP.Enabled = 1
SOAP.IP = "127.0.0.1"
SOAP.Port = 7878
```

Afterwards, run your `worldserver`.

You can use a simple PHP script to run a command to the AzerothCore console like the following,

If you don't have `php-soap`, on Linux Ubuntu you can install it using `sudo apt install php-soap` (or `php7.2-soap`).

```php
<?php

$soap_connection_info = array(
  'soap_uri' => 'urn:AC',
  'soap_host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'soap_port' => '7878',
  'account_name' => 'USERNAME',
  'account_password' => 'PASSWORD'
);

function RemoteCommandWithSOAP($username, $password, $COMMAND)
{
    global $soap_connection_info;
    $result = '';

    try {
        $conn = new SoapClient(NULL, array(
            'location' => 'http://' . $soap_connection_info['soap_host'] . ':' . $soap_connection_info['soap_port'] . '/',
            'uri' => $soap_connection_info['soap_uri'],
            'style' => SOAP_RPC,
            'login' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ));
        $result = $conn->executeCommand(new SoapParam($COMMAND, 'command'));
        unset($conn);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        $result = "Have error on soap!\n";

        if (strpos($e, 'There is no such command') !== false) {
            $result = 'There is no such command!';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo RemoteCommandWithSOAP($soap_connection_info['account_name'], $soap_connection_info['account_password'], ".server info");

?>
```

In the last line you have to change `"account_name"`, `"account_password"` using an account with **gm level 3**.

`echo RemoteCommandWithSOAP($soap_connection_info['account_name'], $soap_connection_info['account_password'], ".server info");`

You can replace `.server info` with any command.

**Note:** this works with other emulators just replacing `urn:AC` with:
- `urn:MaNGOS` for CMaNGOS (and related forks)
- `urn:TC` for TrinityCore
- `urn:SF` for SkyfireProject
- `urn:Oregon` for OregonCore
etc...

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm posting a perl script below to do the same thing for people who don't use PHP, but same, it doesn't work for me and always returns a 403 error

Comment: Alright the solution to 403 error is to have a user with enough privileges, so an admin account with rights on the console (most likely level 4)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl script to do the same thing, it requires libsoap-lite-perl, install with `apt-get install libsoap-lite-perl`

Put the code below in a file named `soap.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite; # visit http://search.cpan.org/dist/SOAP-Lite/ or apt-get install libsoap-lite-perl

my ($user, $pass) = ('gm_account', '1234');
my $host          = 'http://127.0.0.1:7878/';
my $cmd           = '.server info';

BEGIN {
    sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
        return $user => $pass,
    }
}

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    ->proxy($host)
    ->uri('urn:AC');

my $rc = $soap->call('executeCommand',
            SOAP::Data->name('command')->value($cmd));

die $rc->faultstring if ($rc->fault);

print
    $rc->result;
```

Then start your worldserver and run like that `perl soap.pl`.

It should return the result of the command ".server info"