# Cannot get SOAP response from world server

Tags: php, docker, soap, azerothcore

When using the following connection script:

```
<?php
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
$soap_connection_info = array(
  'soap_uri' => 'urn:AC',
  'soap_host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'soap_port' => '7878',
  'account_name' => 'acore',
  'account_password' => 'password'
);

function RemoteCommandWithSOAP($username, $password, $COMMAND)
{
    global $soap_connection_info;
    $result = '';

    try {
        $conn = new SoapClient(NULL, array(
            'location' => 'http://' . $soap_connection_info['soap_host'] . ':' . $soap_connection_info['soap_port'] . '/',
            'uri' => $soap_connection_info['soap_uri'],
            'style' => SOAP_RPC,
            'login' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'compression'   => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE,
        ));
        $result = $conn->executeCommand(new SoapParam($COMMAND, 'command'));
        unset($conn);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = "\nHave error on soap!\n" . $e . "\n";

        if (strpos($e, 'There is no such command') !== false) {
            $result = 'There is no such command!';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

echo RemoteCommandWithSOAP($soap_connection_info['account_name'], $soap_connection_info['account_password'], ".server info");

?>
```

With the world server running and listening to port 7878, I get:

```
local-iMac $ php test.php

Have error on soap!
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /Users/dan/dev/test.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://127.0.0....', 'urn:AC#executeC...', 1, false)
#1 /Users/dan/dev/test.php(26): SoapClient->__call('executeCommand', Array)
#2 /Users/dan/dev/test.php(39): RemoteCommandWithSOAP('acore', 'password', '.server info')
#3 {main}
```

I know error fetching headers points to a possible timeout when waiting for a response but this error comes up instantly as if there was no wait. However I added in the `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);` in my script just to be sure.

My worldserver.conf:

```
# - the DB hostname will be the name of the database docker container
LoginDatabaseInfo     = "ac-database;3306;root;password;acore_auth"
WorldDatabaseInfo     = "ac-database;3306;root;password;acore_world"
CharacterDatabaseInfo = "ac-database;3306;root;password;acore_characters"

# Add more configuration overwrites by copying settings from worldserver.conf.dist
LogLevel = 5
Appender.File=2,5,7,debug.log,w
Logger.network.soap=5,File
Logger.server.worldserver=5,File

# Disable idle connections automatic kick since it doesn't work well on macOS + Docker
CloseIdleConnections = 0

Updates.EnableDatabases = 1
Death.SicknessLevel = -10

SOAP.Enabled = 1
SOAP.IP = "127.0.0.1"
SOAP.Port = 7878
```

And my docker-compose is unchanged:
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Interestingly if I down the world container I will get a different response as if it was connecting when it was up.

```
local-iMac $ php test.php

Have error on soap!
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /Users/dan/dev/test.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://127.0.0....', 'urn:AC#executeC...', 1, false)
#1 /Users/dan/dev/test.php(26): SoapClient->__call('executeCommand', Array)
#2 /Users/dan/dev/test.php(39): RemoteCommandWithSOAP('acore', 'password', '.server info')
#3 {main}
```

Also I enabled worldserver logs to see what was going on in SOAP:

```
2021-09-23_20:41:17 INFO  [server.worldserver] > Using configuration file       /azerothcore/env/dist/etc/worldserver.conf
2021-09-23_20:41:17 INFO  [server.worldserver] > Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020)
2021-09-23_20:41:17 INFO  [server.worldserver] > Using Boost version:           1.71.0
2021-09-23_20:41:17 INFO  [server.worldserver]  
2021-09-23_20:41:17 INFO  [server.worldserver] Process priority class set to -15
2021-09-23_20:41:31 INFO  [network.soap] ACSoap: bound to http://127.0.0.1:7878
```

Also I know container is correctly listening to the port:

```
f166a28ffdf5   acore/ac-wotlk-worldserver-local:master   "./acore.sh run-worl…"   3 weeks ago   Up 48 minutes          0.0.0.0:7878->7878/tcp, :::7878->7878/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp, :::8085->8085/tcp   azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1
```

Some stats on my local:

MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

```
local-iMac $ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
```

```
local-iMac $ php -v
PHP 8.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 26 2021 15:37:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Did you try the perl script posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382665/how-to-send-commands-using-soap-to-azerothcore-worldserver-console to verify it is PHP or worldserver config?

Comment: No, I actually was going try that next. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Heres what I got when I ran your script.
500 Can't connect to 127.0.0.1:7878 (Connection refused) at test.pl line 21.

Comment: $ docker inspect f166a28ffdf5 | grep IPAddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
Thats interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Docker acts like a DHCP server and assigns IP's to the containers. You need to check for what the 'local' IP is and that means 'local' to docker.

`docker inspect <containerID> | grep IPAddress`

That is the ip you need to bind to in your config.

```
SOAP.Enabled = 1
SOAP.IP = "172.19.0.3"
SOAP.Port = 7878
```